# Need to fake/mock an internet-connection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mocking, microsoft-fakes

I'm running some unit-tests, and I need to know how my program is going to respond without internet-connection. Is there a way to make Visual Studio belive, that there is no internet-connection? Fx. by using fakes, shims, mocks etc?
I know, that I can just shut down the internet manually, but I would like to do it, by using code.

Any input would be gratefully appreciated! =)

Thanks!

Comment: Make your *program* believe it, not VS.  Do you have a function/class in your code you could return with a fake that would tell your program  that the internet is disconnected?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the real code with an internet call, use an interface and inject that into the calling code.

You can use a framework like [moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) to simulate the internet call and test just the logic in the calling code.